# angular equivalent vue v-bind="$props"

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js

If i'm lazy i could use `v-bind="$props"` to dynamic set key value like below sample :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>

<script>
  Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: `
      <svg>
        <circle v-bind="circle"> </circle>
      </svg>
    `,
    computed: {
      circle() {
        return {
          cx: '50%',
          cy: '50%',
          r: '45%',
          'stroke-width': '10%'
        }
      }
    }
  })

  new Vue({
    el: '#app'
  })
</script>
```

output :

```html
<svg><circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" stroke-width="10%"></circle></svg>
```

Does angular have such a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Inputs in Angular

```
<circle [data]="circle"> </circle>
```

circle could be an object or an method (not recommended because of change detection).

Better: You can use a pipe

```
<circle [data]="circle | getMyData"> </circle>
```

Comment: it alert `Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'xxx'.`

Comment: You need an component with @Input() data. For example circle is an component and in the ts file you can use @Input() data. In the html of the circle component you has the data binding.

Comment: In your example in the app.component.html you can use data as variable